# why malloc always failed allocate memory (roughtly 9GB but I have 16GB physical memory)?

Tags: c++, c

I believe I have enough memory (16G) for this allocation in my ubuntu (64 bit application). 
But still it always return NULL.

Following is my memory information by running free command.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16376100    3295024   13081076      41936      88852    1073808
-/+ buffers/cache:    2132364   14243736
Swap:     15998972          0   15998972
```

#### Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjW27.png]

Comment: Are you sure you have enough contiguous memory for the allocation?

Comment: I am sure, I provide the memory information by running free. is that i am wrong? and it is 64 bit.

Comment: what is the type of `n_dataset`?

Comment: Your total contiguous memory could be entirely different from your total free memory. Imagine if you had a million 4 byte boxes. You can never allocated 6 bytes into any one box, even though you have a million of them.

Comment: @user975989 I understand what you say. the contiguous memory may not so big. but if i really need allocate large memory for big array, which command or method you prefer?

Comment: Are you *running* on x64 or *compiling* for x64? Please check `sizeof (void *)`. If it's 4, then you're compiling for x32.

Comment: @mch it is big number. n_dataset = 2453688725

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it is 8 (unsigned long), so i can confirm it is 64 bit application?

Comment: Yes, it is. You're doing it correctly.

Comment: try `mmap`. Also please refrain from posting screenshots of programs, pick one language out of C and C++, and do not cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: You are doing this correctly, but it is very likely to fail anyway, whatever you do. Do you really need that large a block at once? Can't you cut up whatever you want to do in smaller portions?

Comment: It looks like the multiplication of `2453688725` with the `sizeof (struct train_pair)` is causing an overflow and yielding a negative number, which when translated to unsigned long is `1224820312` (this is smaller than `n_dataset`). What is the size of the struct ?

Comment: I have 8GB physical memory, able to allocate 12GB (using virtual memory).

Comment: You should cast to `size_t`: `void *A = malloc((size_t)1024*1024*1024*12);`

Comment: @user1952500 sizeof (struct train_pair) is 4.

Comment: @SanqiangZhao, can you try typecasting to `malloc((size_t)2453688725 * sizeof(struct train_pair))`

Comment: Your code execution is subject to kernel restrictions as set in sysctl and subject to limits. Make sure you are running your code with unlimited limits and the kernel is set to allow over commitment.

Comment: @Rotem you are correct, that is because the number is overflow. could i ask why allocation is still failed since even it is overlowed it is also a positive number.

Comment: @user1952500 you are correct, that is because the number is overflow. could i ask why allocation is still failed since even it is overlowed it is also a positive number.

Comment: Physical memory is irrelevant to `malloc()`, it uses virtual memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comment, I figured it out. that's because when I calculate the memory size, the sum is overflowed.

Another case is I use `int n_dataset = 2453688725;` which is overflowed, `n_dataset` will be negative number.

Comment: Sizes should be expressed using type `size_t`, not `int`.